# VS Code editor: how select everything until next tag - or next occurent of <

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, editing

There are keyboard shortcuts to select everything between matching brackets and to grow and shrink your selecting, however sometimes there is another markup inside. Is there a way to select everything from coursor to beginning of the next element? For example the cursor sits after the

tag. When pressing shortcut I want to:

```
<p>Select only this text<span>and not this</span>, also not this.</p>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by).

In your `settings.json`

```
  "selectby.regexes": {
    "till-angle-bracket": {
      "forward": "<",
      "forwardInclude": false
    }
  }
```

You can use the command **Select text range based on regex** and select `till-angle-bracket` from the list

or you can add a keybinding

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+y", // or any other key-combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "selectby.regex",
    "args": ["till-angle-bracket"]
  }
```

Comment: this works fantastic, thank you very much! you are saving me so much time and finger fatigue!